# Looking for a Boy's Love story with an old man and a ghost in a cabin in the woods

Tags: story-identification, comics, ghost

The comic starts in a cabin in the woods in which an old man is sitting on the front porch, while carving a tiny wooden sculpture. Then a ghostly like creature is looking at him. The old man asks him why he's here, but the creature doesn't reply.

Time goes on and they have bonded, and soon it turns into romance, until a saleslady shows up to present the cabin to a straight couple. Later on, it's revealed that the old man is also a ghost as well. The creature ask the the old man that all right for the couple to stay at his house and replies he's fine with it.

Cut back to the front porch, they leave a small wooden sculpture as a gift to the recent couple who moved in, which they notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this on Reddit and they solved it! This is *[Houseguest](https://www.pillowfort.social/posts/376923)* by Reapersun (T Zysk)

[image]